# neo4j in subfolder behind nginx reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, neo4j

I have neo4j running in a docker container that is reachable via an nginx server (running on the host). Now I want to move all requests into a subfolder (i.e. http ://myserver/neo4j/***): I tried the following proxy setting:

```
    location /neo4j/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:7474/;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_buffering off;
    }
```

This seems to work, but the neo4j server does not respect the /neo4j/ prefix and I found no option for setting this path in the neo4j settings file. This  means that the neo4j server issues urls such as http://myserver/browser instead of http://myserver/neo4j/browser. Is there an option in neo4j to configure this properly?

Comment: Did you figure out this?